# Web View Not Displaying Content in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, webview

I was following a tutorial to display content from a web view within my application. In swift 2.0, when I run the emulator I am getting no response on the emulator screen.

My code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.stackoverflow.com")

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {
        (data, response, error) in

        if error == nil {

            var urlContent = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

            print(urlContent)

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

                self.webView.loadHTMLString(urlContent! as String, baseURL: nil)

            }

        }


    }

    task.resume()


   }

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

[image]

Comment: Your code works for me. Are you sure your outlets are set up properly in your storyboard or xib?

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure you should try to retain your data task.

Just declare stored property:

```
var task: NSURLSessionDataTask?

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.stackoverflow.com")

task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {
    (data, response, error) in

    if error == nil {

        var urlContent = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        print(urlContent)

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

            self.webView.loadHTMLString(urlContent! as String, baseURL: nil)
            self.task = nil

        }

    }


}

task.resume()
```